# Dynamic url path for Business Catalyst web app products

Tags: business-catalyst

I am helping a developer friend of mine scaffold out a simple website for his client which of all places, they chose Adobe's Business Catalyst.  I am sure it has it's merits, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to specify a dynamic url path on a product description/detail.

Here is an overview of my issue; I hope it makes sense.  I created a web app called 'products' and then created a few dozen custom input fields. I then created all the pages for their site and on one of the product pages,  I added a web app module from my 'products' web app and classified as 'healthcare' for an output of http://mcifoods.businesscatalyst.com/healthcare/breakfast-products-healthcare.html - I am only testing the workflow, which is the reason for it's simplicity.  The issue I am having is if you click on the link to view the product detail, it takes you to the `/product/test-1` page, but I need it to go to `/healthcare/breakfast-products-healthcare/test-1` path, which is the proper way, but I can't figure it out in Business Catalyst.

If this is impossible, please put me out of my misery, but if I am missing something obvious, I would be very grateful for the push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the URL is specified is like so:

```
site-url.com/[web-app-name]/[web-app-item-name]
```

The only portion of the URL you can change is the `web-app-item-name` and nothing else.

Depending upon what you are doing, it may be better to use another part of the system, such as the ecommerce portion as that will allow you to create the URL structure you are looking for.